# trigger assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tying to complete my assignment but i am facing some problem so i need your help
I have craeted a table name client contain 6 columns name(c_id,c_name,c_transfer,c_balance,day,time) now the assignment is that i have to create a trigger in which is day column contain Satauarday and Sunday it prints Sorry Bank closed and if time column contain 05:00 to 09:00 it will inserted but if the time is not reguarding the condition row cant inserted.
The codes are as follows:

```
create table client
(
c_id int identity primary key,
c_name varchar(50),
c_transfer money,
c_balance money,
[date] datetime,
[day] varchar(50),
)

alter trigger transactions
ON client
for Insert 
as
begin
    if(select top 1 [day] from client order by c_id desc)='Satuarday'
    begin
    print'Sorry Bank is closed today'
    rollback;
    commit;
    end
    if(select top 1 [day] from client order by c_id desc)= 'Sunday'
    begin
    print'Sorry Bank is closed today'
    rollback;
    commit;
    end
    if(select top 1 date from client order by c_id desc)not in (DATEDIFF(hh,'09:00','05:00'))
    begin
    print'Sorry Bank time is not this...'
    rollback;
    commit;
    end
end
```

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? I'm pretty sure the error is with `rollback; commit;` - there are a couple of problems there. But I'd like to see the error to be sure.

Comment: sorry i am trying to execute the code i am totally confused if their is any mistake you found please mention and correct it please.

Comment: You cannot use both a rollback and a commit. A rollback erases all data modifications made from the start of the transaction . A commit accepts these changes and makes them a permanent part of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `Inserted` table. This table can be used inside a `FOR INSERT` trigger and contains the row that is being inserted.

```
GO
CREATE TRIGGER transactions
ON client
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT [day] FROM inserted 
            WHERE ([day] IN ('saturday', 'sunday')) 
            OR (DATEPART(hh,[date]) <= 5) OR DATEPART(hh,[date]) >= 9)
  BEGIN
    PRINT'Sorry Bank is closed at this time.'
    ROLLBACK;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: The Inserted table can also be found in FOR UPDATE triggers.  Also your trigger assumes only one row being inserted at a time and may get odd results if more than one row from different days is inserted.

Comment: ok this is done but i am confuse in time column i want that if the time inserted greater than 9:00 and less than 5:00 row cant insert.

Comment: Kenneth Fisher made a good point. I changed the trigger so I should work for multi row inserts now. However, it will rollback ALL rows now even if only 1 does not meet the requirements.